# Error with @nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to when updating Angular from 10 to 11

Tags: angular

This is my first time updating Angular. The version is 10.2.3, i need to update to 11. I am following the guide from the official documentation.

I encountered an error in the console `"Package "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" (extended), would install "11.2.14"`.

On the page of this package you can only install under version 9 and 13.14.
I tried `"npm install @nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to"` - it didn't help. What do I need to do?